# WPF Drawing images leaves unexpected empty line of pixels

Tags: wpf, drawingcontext

I'm trying to render multiple images in WPF onto a canvas. In the following contrived example, I was able to reproduce the unexpected behavior using following code:

```
public class MyCanvas : Canvas
{
    protect override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(1, 1, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Indexed8, BitmapPalettes.Gray256, new byte[] { 0 }, 2);
        drawingContext.DrawImage(image, new Rect(10, 10, 128, 128));
        drawingContext.DrawImage(image, new Rect(10, 138, 128, 128));
    }
}
```

This results in the following drawing:
[Drawing with thin line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwuub.png).
As you can see, there is thin (probably one pixel) wide line,between the two rectangles. I expected a drawing, where both rectangles touch.

**So my question is:**
Why doesn't WPF render the images as touching?

Comment: Can't reproduce it. It might be an aliasing issue. Try setting `RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(this, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor)` on the Canvas.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, but thanks for the hint anyway. I will keep this in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your help. `RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(this, EdgeMode.Aliased)` did the trick

Comment: Great. Just a note, the last argument to BitmapSource.Create, the stride, should be 1, not 2.